# Increase virtual memory size with batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, virtual-memory

I came across with following thread a while ago: [post about virtual space][1].

```
start /wait /b powershell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management' -Name 'PagingFiles' -Value 'c:\pagefile.sys 1024 1024, d:\pagefile.sys 4096 4096'"
```

I was wondering if it is possible to add to it autodetection of currently installed RAM size and multiplying it on 3.

As I know the recommended maximum size of your virtual space is 3x of your current RAM, so is it possible to make a batch that does it with a single click?

I assume you must set variable via cmd and include it in the code which you have listed above, something like:

```
start /wait /b powershell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management' -Name 'PagingFiles' -Value 'c:\pagefile.sys **AUTODETECTCURRENTRAM** **AUTODETECTCURRENTRAM*3**, d:\pagefile.sys 4096 4096'"
```

I would love to hear your opinion about it, how do you think is it possible to achieve this? And how useful would it be for improving computer performance?

Comment: To get memory information you could use `wmic MemPhysical get MaxCapacity` and `wmic OS get TotalVirtualMemorySize`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you're looking for a batch file with content something like this:

```batch-file
@PowerShell -NoProfile -Command ^
 "$TotalRAM = (GWMI Win32_PhysicalMemory|Measure Capacity -Sum).Sum/1MB;" ^
 "$VirtualM = $TotalRAM * 3;" ^
 "Set-ItemProperty -Path \"Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\" -Name \"PagingFiles\" -Type \"MultiString\" -Value \"C:\pagefile.sys $TotalRAM $VirtualM`r`nD:\pagefile.sys 4096 4096\" -Force"
```

This should create a REG_MULTI_SZ entry with the first listed at the root of `C:` with its initial size matching your total physical RAM, and its maximum, three times that set for initial. The second listed on the root of `D:` with both initial and maximum sizes of 4096 MB.

*Please note, that this answer is not a recommendation, I do not see any need whatsoever for assuming that Microsoft does not know better than I how to manage such things.*

Answer (score 2):

Total ram can be Acquired using systeminfo, though it's not a silent or fast process

```bat
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /I /C:"Total Physical Memory"') do Set "TotalRAM=%%a"
Set "TotalRAM=%TotalRAM: =%"
Set "TotalRAM=%TotalRAM:,=%"
Set "TotalRAM=%TotalRAM:MB=%"
```

As for whether your intended purpose will have any benefit, I wouldn't know.

To find current max virtual memory:

```bat
for /f "tokens=3* delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /I /C:"Virtual Memory: Max Size:"') do Set "maxVRAM=%%a"
Set "maxVRAM=%maxVRAM: =%"
Set "maxVRAM=%maxVRAM:,=%"
Set "maxVRAM=%maxVRAM:MB=%"
```